# Microsoft Word is there a difference between HTML Format and Formatted Text (RTF) when pasting tables from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

**Problem:**
At work I routinely create large word documents (100+ pages, mostly filled with tables). Often these documents are extremely slow to edit due to the large tables. I have the option to special paste Excel tables into Word as "HTML Format" or "Formatted Text (RTF)".

**Questions:** What is the difference between these two paste options? And, more importantly, **is there a difference in performance between the two?**

Comment: Most probably Word process tables in its own internal format and there will be no difference, but it's only a guess.

Comment: RTF supports text formatting, including bullets, alignment, and linked objects. HTML lets you use HTML formatting.